# Solr Grouping parameter group.format=simple not working for me

Tags: solr, lucene

I am grouping my solr query results,so it results in multiple groups. To combine all these group's results in one list I am using `"group.format=simple"`. But I don't see it working.Can someone help me on this or provide a sample of how result will look if `"group.format=simple"` is working. Please help

Solr Query:

http://localhost:8983/solr/core/select?q=((value1:"solr search")^10 OR(value1:solr AND value1:search)^9) OR (value1:solr OR value1:search)&fl=id,score&group.limit=5&group=true&group.query=(value1:"solr search")&group.query=((value1:solr AND value1:search)-(value1:"solr search"))&group.query=((value1:solr OR value1:search)-(value1:"solr search")-(value1:solr AND value1:search))&group.format=simple&group.sort=plan desc&wt=json

Response:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 5,
    "params": {
      "q": "((value1:\"solr search\")^10 OR\r\n(value1:solr AND value1:search)^9) OR value1:solr OR value1:search",
      "group.sort": "plan desc",
      "group.format": "simple",
      "fl": "id,score",
      "group.limit": "5",
      "group.query": [
        "(value1:\"solr search\")",
        "((value1:solr AND value1:search)-(value1:\"solr search\"))",
        "((value1:solr OR value1:search)-(value1:\"solr search\") -(value1:solr AND value1:search))"
      ],
      "wt": "json",
      "group": "true"
    }
  },
  "grouped": {
    "(value1:\"solr search\")": {
      "matches": 21401,
      "doclist": {
        "numFound": 110,
        "start": 0,
        "maxScore": 66.0048,
        "docs": [
          {
            "id": "MBO088",
            "score": 47.717316
          },
          {
            "id": "MBO010",
            "score": 52.34251
          },
          {
            "id": "MCC011",
            "score": 62.8052
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "((value1:solr AND value1:search)-(value1:\"solr search\"))": {
      "matches": 21401,
      "doclist": {
        "numFound": 4825,
        "start": 0,
        "maxScore": 32.28555,
        "docs": [
          {
            "id": "MAA514",
            "score": 21.143295
          },
          {
            "id": "MAA516",
            "score": 21.143295
          },
          {
            "id": "MAA518",
            "score": 21.143295
          },
          {
            "id": "MAA520",
            "score": 21.143295
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "((value1:solr OR value1:search)-(value1:\"solr search\") -(value1:solr AND value1:search))": {
      "matches": 21401,
      "doclist": {
        "numFound": 16466,
        "start": 0,
        "maxScore": 2.1915653,
        "docs": [
          {
            "id": "MPA024",
            "score": 0.888321
          },
          {
            "id": "MAA502",
            "score": 1.317673
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add an example of what you're getting back and what you expected to get back.

Comment: I have added solr query and its result.

Comment: What happens if you pass `group.main=true` as suggested on the Solr guide https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/result-grouping.html#grouping-results-by-field ?

Comment: In case of group.main=true its returning only one group as result, which is different from what I want.

Comment: Not sure if I understood the requirement here. are you trying to get only 1 result group when you are passing multiple `group.query` parameter or you want a merged result set of all the `group.query` params ? 
could you please add the expected response vs the current response here.

Comment: Yes, i have 3 group.query parameters which is resulting 3 groups but I want to merge result of these group into one list. So say group1 returns 2 results, group2 returns 3 results and group3 returns 1 result. So as a result i want to return these 6 results in one list. I hope you are clear on it.

Comment: Please help me on this